# GULP : When and how to use concatenation and minification in a a project

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I am developing a single page application.  It is all pure html / css / javascript and I am just starting to set up my gulp file.  I figured out how to concatenate and minify my css and javascript into one main file and I just am wondering on workflow with this scenario.

**The pros :**

- its going to make my app run faster

**The Cons :**

- During development on my localhost, it makes it hard to track down line numbers and files when its minified / concatenated.

**Some questions:**

- Has anyone developed a good gulp workflow that allows concatenation /
  minification that doesn't impede workflow during production?
- That serves only concatenated / minified file on staging or live server?
- Or do you just wait until close to testing the site and then allow concatenation / minification and change all your links to point to
  the single  main css / js file?
- Note : keep in mind this is a single page application without any server-side coding or JS MVC

Thanks for any suggestions,

david